# use button to write text to the page

Tags: javascript

I can do this with a alert but I want to print the results of a function directly to the web page.

When the user clicks the car button I want the results from the `car()` function to write into my `id="mainContent"` div.

if the user clicks the Ice Cream button I want the results from the ice cream button to replace what ever is in the `mainConten`t div with the results from the `iceCream()` function

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php

Comment: Thank you for this link this was VERY helpful. I am having trouble finding a reference that I can understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have some code like this:

```
<form id="ice_cream_form" action="fake" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Ice Cream" />
</form>
```

You could use some JavaScript code like this:

```
var form=document.getElementById("ice_cream_form");
var mainContent=document.getElementById("mainContent");
if(form.addEventListener) {
    form.addEventListener("submit", submitted, false);
}else if(form.attachEvent) {
    form.attachEvent("onsubmit", function() {
        return submitted(window.event);
    });
}
function submitted(event) {
    if("textContent" in mainContent) {
        mainContent.textContent=iceCream();
    }else{
        mainContent.innerText=iceCream();
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
}
```

If `iceCream` returns HTML you want to display rather than plain text you want to display, you'll probably want to replace the part that changes `textContent` to just set `innerHTML`.

Alternatively, you could use inline event handlers (although I don't really like this method because it mixes content and behavior):

```
<input type="button" value="Ice Cream" onclick="document.getElementById('mainContent').textContent=iceCream(); return false;" />
```

Comment: You may want to mention the problems this may have with IE, such as `addEventListener()`/`attachEvent()` and IE's use of `innerText` instead of `textContent`.

Comment: @alex: Yes; I probably should.

Answer (score 2):

```
var mainContent = document.getElementById('mainContent');
carButton.onclick = function() {
    mainContent.appendChild(document.createTextNode(car()));
}
```

Comment: I take it that text node method is more efficient than `.innerHTML += carstuff;`...

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Should be, not to mention it won't destroy anything that can't be serialised into a HTML string and reparsed.

Comment: Can someone explain node to me?

Comment: @EdwardNickAJubrey: A text node is a node consisting of text that isn't an element.

Answer (score 0):

When, for example, the car button is clicked, this code should be run:

```
document.getElementById("mainContent").appendChild(
    document.createTextNode(car())); /* ← there is the magic */
```

If you don’t know how to register this function to be launched in case of clicking the button.
Then do it like this:

```
var button = document.getElementById("idOfTheButton");
button.addEventListener("click",
    function()
    {
        document.getElementById("mainContent").appendChild(
            document.createTextNode(car()));
    }, 1);
```

Adapt this code appropriately for the other button and it will work too.